# Add a matrix outside a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that gives me a matrix of 17*3 (float (17,3)). I call that function again and again in a loop, i want to add the matrices so that rows remain 17 but column keeps on adding to make one big matrix.

Comment: Yes i have used np.array

Comment: You can probably use `np.hstack(map(your_function, the_list_with_your_inputs))`. Add a sample input and expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please check this guide about **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** so that we can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without NUMPY:

Transpose the matrix first because you are not gonna touch the 17 rows.

```
# a matrix is 17 * 3
a_transpose = [[a[j][i] for j in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a[0]))]
```

Then, add the column of 17 rows as one row of 17 columns

```
a_transpose.append([1,2,3, ... 17])
```

Once, you are done adding several rows, transpose the matrix back as said above. That way, you don't iterate through your array 17 times everytime you add a column to your matrix.

### With NUMPY:

Transpose

```
# a matrix is 17 * 3
a = numpy.array(a)
a_transpose = a.transpose()
```

Add a row (17 column values you wanted to add)

```
a_transpose.append([1,2,3, .... 17], axis=0)
```

Comment: Careful here.  The first may work because `a_transpose` is a list, and lists have an `append` method.  The second won't work, because arrays don't have an append method.  And you shouldn't use `np.append` in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
In [187]: def foo(i): 
     ...:     return np.arange(i,i+6).reshape(3,2) 
     ...:
```

Iteratively build a list of arrays:

```
In [188]: alist = []                                                            
In [189]: for i in range(4): 
     ...:     alist.append(foo(i)) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [190]: alist                                                                 
Out[190]: 
[array([[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]]), array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]), array([[2, 3],
        [4, 5],
        [6, 7]]), array([[3, 4],
        [5, 6],
        [7, 8]])]
```

Make an array from that list:

```
In [191]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)                                         
Out[191]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8]])
```